# Mixing classic ADO and ADO.NET database access w/ transactions

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp-classic, ado.net, ado

We are trying to get an old classic ASP web app that uses classic ADO upgraded, but the app is huge and we can only do parts of it. Specifically, there is a VB5-based .dll that the app calls using OLE/COM. And, it passes in a database connection (that uses classic ADO). The .dll does some work and returns to the ASP level. The database connection has an active transaction on it so that any error at the ASP level or inside the .dll can be undone with a rollback. All has worked fine for years.

But, now we need to rewrite the .dll in C#. I know how to solve the "classic ASP access it via COM" issues, etc. What I need thoughts on is the database connection.

The ASP level has a classic ADO connection object open and with an active transaction.

I need to turn this object into a ADO.NET connection object, carrying along the transaction. I'd just open up a second connection, but (a) the transaction is needed and (b) the second connection would immediately block as there are transaction locks by the time the .dll gets the connection.

If I could extract the "underlying connection" from either classic ADO or ADO.NET and create the connection object in the other style using that, I think things would work.

And, yes, I'm crazy. But, this is a huge application and can only be moved slowly. There are hundreds of classic ASP pages. Etc. Thanks for any help.

Comment: you are probably better off re-writing the entire classic asp code into asp.net code.. had to do that last year with a application that we inherited it works like a charm when we took the time to split the forms and converted everything to .net

Comment: What about distributed transactions, so you can have both transactions alive and rollback both if needed?